# Union of two 3x3 matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find the Union of two sets of matrices.
The first set is all diagonal matrices, for example $$A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & b & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and the second is the set of opposite diagonal matrices, for example $$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & c \\
        0 & b & 0 \\
        a & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand that the union is a collection of elements which are in A and B or both A and B, but i'm not sure how this works with matrices. Would it just be some set of matrices of the form $$C =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 & b \\
        0 & c & 0 \\
        d & 0 & e \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$?

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is no reason why the definition of set union would be any different when the elements of the sets are matrices compared to when they are elements of any other type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two sets of matrices: the set $\mathcal{A}$ of matrices of the form $A$ for $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}$, and the set $\mathcal{B}$ of matrices of the form $B$.

I don't know what the union of *matrices* means, but I guess you are considering the union of the two sets. In that case, $C$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$ nor $\mathcal{B}$ for non-trivial values of $d$ and $c$. The union would then be the set of matrices of the form $A$ or $B$.

Note: the intersection would be the matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$.

Comment: However, $C$ is in the sum of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ (considered as subspaces of the vector space of all $3 \times 3$ real matrices).

Comment: @arkeet Yes, but I don't think this would be referred to as "union", because it contains elements which are neither in $\mathcal{A}$ or $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a little confused. So $A \cup B$ is all of the matrices of the form $A$ or $B$?

Comment: @J.Doe Well, that the only definition of union which would make sense to me. How do you define the union of matrices? Or did you mean the union of _sets_ of matrices as I assumed in my answer?

Comment: @anderstood I agree, it was a rather tangential comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean the set of matrices

Comment: @J.Doe Then you can apply the definition of the union of sets and see that it's what I indicated in the answer.

Comment: @anderstood Ok, thank you.